# Extracting value from a string in java

Tags: java

I have a string, and I want to extract the text **abcd** from this string. I useed the `indexOf()` method to get the start index, but how we can I set the end index value? The **abcd** text value is dynamic, so we can't hardcode it like `startIndex()+5`. I need some logical code.

```
String str = "Hi Welcome to stackoverflow : " +"\n"+"Information :"+"\n"+"hostname : abcd"+"\n"+
"questiontype : text"+"value : desc.";

if(str.contains("hostname : "))
{
String value = "hostname : "
int startIndex = str.indexof("hostname : ") + value.length();
// how to find the endIndex() in that case
}
```

Comment: These may be useful: [`String::substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)), [`String::indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)), [`String::length`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#length()).

Comment: You can look for what comes after the abcd-value and use this information to get an endIndex.

Comment: How to find the end index?  The question is the answer: it depends on what defines the end of the text.

Comment: You can't really know how long the remaining value is, unless you specify a structure to which this text conforms. It seems that after each value, a newline is present, so you could simply search for the newline after the key with `str.substring(startIndex, str.indexOf("\n", startIndex))`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String answer = str.substring( str.indexOf( value) + value.length(), str.indexOf( "questiontype :" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the string after `"hostname : "` you can do:

```
String str = "Hi Welcome to stackoverflow : " +"\n"+"Information :"+"\n"+"hostname : abcde"+"\n"+
        "questiontype : text"+"value : desc.";
    

int startIndex = str.indexOf("hostname") + "hostname : ".length();
int endIndex = str.indexOf("questiontype") - 1;

String result = str.substring(startIndex, endIndex);

System.out.println(result);
```

Also note that you can add `\n` to the text of the string without needing to append it so that: `"Hi Welcome to stackoverflow : " +"\n"+"Information..."` would work just as fine doing: `"Hi Welcome to stackoverflow : \nInformation..."`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not as efficient as the answers with indexOf, a regex solution is succint.

```
Optional<String> getValue(String properties, String keyName) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^|\\R)" + keyName + "\\s*:\\s*(.*)(\\R|$)");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(properties);
    return m.find() ? Optional.of(m.group(2)) : Optional.emtpy();
}

String hostname = getValue("...\nhostname : abc\n...", 
                           "hostname").orElse("localhost");
```